# predict lm function in R (multiple linear regression)

Tags: r, lm, predict

I did a multiple linear regression in R using the function lm and I want to use it to predict several values. So I'm trying to use the function `predict()`.
Here is my code:

```
new=data.frame(t=c(10, 20, 30))
v=1/t
LinReg<-lm(p ~ log(t) + v)
Pred=predict(LinReg, new, interval="confidence")
```

So I would like to predict the values of p when `t=c(10,20,30...)`. However, this is not working and I don't see why. The error message I get is:

> "Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : variable lengths differ (found for 'vart')
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   'newdata' had 3 rows but variables found have 132 rows "

132 is the length of my vector of variables upon which I run the regression. I checked my vector 1/t and it is well-defined and has the right number of coefficients. What is curious is that if I do a simple linear regression (of one variable), the same code works well...

```
new=data.frame(t=c(10, 20, 30))
LinReg<-lm(p ~ log(t))
Pred=predict(LinReg, new, interval="confidence")
```

Can anyone help me please! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you defined `v` as a new, distinct variable from `t` when you fit your model. R doesn't remember how a variable was created so it doesn't know that `v` is a function of `t` when you fit the model. So when you go to predict values, it uses the existing values of `v` which would have a different length than the new values of `t` you are specifying.

Instead you want to fit

```
new <- data.frame(t=c(10, 20, 30))
LinReg <- lm(p ~ log(t) + I(1/t))
Pred <- predict(LinReg, new, interval="confidence")
```

If you did want `v` to be a completely independent variable, then you would need to supply values for `v` as well in your `new` data.frame in order to predict `p`.